# Accessing ee.ImageCollection("NOAA/GOES/16/FDCC") from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, noaa, goes-16

Can you advise if ImageCollection("NOAA/GOES/16/FDCC") from [GOES-16 FDCC Series ABI Level 2 Fire/Hot Spot Characterization CONUS](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NOAA_GOES_16_FDCC?authuser=1&hl=en#description) contain any data?

I was trying to review the map with Earth Engine's Code Editor but nothing was loaded into the map.

If Google Earth Engine is not the best source to access this data, what will you recommend for GOES-16 FDCC Series ABI Level 2 Fire/Hot Spot Characterization CONUS data?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  It emphasizes that there should be only one question asked per question.  I recommend reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 for tips on how to structure a good question.

Answer (score 1):

Earth Engine is a good source for this data, and `NOAA/GOES/16/FDCC` contains a lot of data.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/0438200515e35fb4fed08de6f23df834

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/GOES/16/FDCC')
  .filterDate('2020-07-01', '2020-07-02')
  .filterBounds(geometry)
Map.addLayer(collection.max())
Map.centerObject(geometry)
print(collection.size()) // 288 images in 2020-07-01
```